Flutter google sign in not working in production playstore
I've recently published my app on playstore and noticed the google sign in feature is not working.
I've used the google_sign_in package and from the sentry log this is the error I've got .
From the documentation it indicates a misconfiguration in the google sign in , more precisely that the sha-1 key has not been registered on firebase console.Note that I've generated many release build apk for testing and it has always been working.
I went to the firebase console and added my sha-1 and sha-256 keys(production ones from my jks file) and also from this post I've added the sha-1 key generated by google in the playstore developer console , regenerated google-services.json file and firebase_options, flutter clean and reuploaded but still not working.
I've noticed the sha-1 key from playstore console indicates in the firebase console that it is already in use in combination with my app package name in another project . I've check in the corresponding project in google cloud console and the sha-1 key is nowhere to be find in oauth2 clients but I cannot add it as it says it already exist. Also there is another project in the google cloud console which seems to be a duplicate of my project but I don't have any authorization there, even seeing the key and also cannot see who is the admin of this project, so I'm a bit confused and don't know what to do.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Go to Google Cloud -> APIs & Services -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
Check whether you added sha-1 key which was generated by Google Play console

